# Dynamically assigning data attribute to svg object

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, snap.svg

I have a page where i open a modal and i want that each time it is opened a new svg image is displayed there.

```
<div class="col s3 center-align" id="event_logo">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="" id="literary_logo_object" class="event_logo_object" ></object>
</div>
```

I want to assign the `data` attribute of `<object>` dynamically.

What i tried is

```
document.getElementById('literary_logo_object').setAttribute('data','svg/literary.svg');
var event_logo = Snap(Snap("#literary_logo_object").node);
```

It seems that changing the attribute `data` is not allowed like this. After adding the last line, i get the following error

```
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute height="undefined"
Error: Invalid value for <svg> attribute width="undefined"
```

both the errors are in line 930 of snap.svg.js, which is very highly unlikely.

**What else i have tried**

I readily defined the object tag like this

```
<div class="col s3 center-align" id="event_logo">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="svg/literary.svg" id="literary_logo_object" class="event_logo_object" ></object>
</div>
```

and made it hide, i.e., `display : none`

then i tried unhiding the object like

```
$("#literary_logo_object").show();
var event_logo = Snap("#literary_logo_object").node;
```

again after the second line i am getting the same error.

Comment: I don't know "snap" but it appears that the attribute height/width on the object is getting accessed by "snap" and as there is none of them an undefined error occurs. What if you add those to your object element?

Comment: Ok, are they present in your svg?

Comment: @LGSon yes they are present.

Comment: Ok, then I can't do more as I don't know "snap"

Comment: I just checked the console with a **[demo here](http://codepen.io/kshkrao3/pen/xZxEvo)** but I see a different `error` and with that `error` I can say its expecting you to pass `tagName` instead of `id`

Answer (score 0):

Its not quite clear what you are attempting, ie I'm not sure why you are using Snap (yet) for this.

```
document.getElementById('literary_logo_object').setAttribute('data','svg/literary.svg');
```

The above should load the new svg in place, thats it.

You don't need Snap for this, as you aren't doing anything with the svg.

I'm also not sure why you don't just use a Snap.load() function, or is there some specific reason you need an object tag ?

If you want to then do something with the SVG thats loaded, you can reference it with 'contentDocument' (as this is in a different document), so using Snap it would look something like this...

```
var obj = document.getElementById('literary_logo_object');
obj.setAttribute('data','svg/literary.svg');

obj.onload = function( ev ) {    // it may take a while to load
  Snap( obj.contentDocument.getElementById("someElInsideSvg") )
       .animate({ transform: 't-400,-400' }, 2000); //do whatever
}
```